# How to delete TiWorker?

Tags: windows

TiWorker is causing huge CPU usage, and keeps coming back.

I tried all the options in these links, and non of them worked. It just keeps coming back. I tried to set it to low priority. I tried to install updates manually. I deleted `SoftwareDistribution`, and other suggestions.

https://windowsreport.com/windows-8-high-disk-usage-caused-tiworker-exe/

https://whatsabyte.com/windows/fix-tiworker-exe-high-cpu-problem/

I'm sick and tired of Windows and Microsoft's strategies. I wanna delete this file, but it seems that OS doesn't let me. How can I delete it?

**Update**: This has become a hugely annoying problem. This file keeps coming back even after being deleted entirely, and keeps consuming high portions of CPU each 10 minutes. Any help in this regards is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone suffering from this annoying process, first you need to find all of the instances of `TiWorker`. Since Windows default search is too slow, and you should search everywhere for it, I recommend that you download a search engine for Windows. I personally use [Everything from Voidtools](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/). So, search for `TiWorker.exe`.

Then for each instance, try to change ownership of the file to your user. Then you can delete them.

Note: If you don't change ownership, you won't be able to delete it, since TrustedInstaller prevents you.

Comment: Well, I deleted all instances, and to my surprise, after an hour it simply came back. From nowhere. Is Windows self-healing?

Answer (score 0):

[The TiWorker.exe process is part of the Windows Update Service](https://www.electronicshub.org/tiworker-exe#3_Restart_the_Windows_Update_Service) and you should definitely *not* delete that file!

On Windows 8 and earlier versions of Windows, just turn off Windows Update.

On Windows 10, it is officially not possible to disable Windows Update.
But [I have posted instructions on how to permanently disable Windows Update on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1720522).
That method has served me well for many years,
and allows you to easily to restore Windows Update whenever you want.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/a/849276.